# Add Manjaro repositories to Arch during install

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro, repository, stability

I know it's a terrible idea to add Manjaro repositories to Arch Linux, but would it be possible to add the repositories to a custom installer made using `archiso`?

How would I do that?

( I want to create a distro with custom desktop, custom graphical toolkit, custom apps, custom installer, etc, but I want the stability of Manjaro )

Comment: Why not just modify Manjaro then? Why are you starting from Arch?

Comment: Because I don't want all the bloat from Manjaro, I don't want a desktop environment, Calamares and all the stuff they add. I just want a clean base with a little stabler repositories. I don't want to go through deleting 80% of the iso content to make it like a clean Arch base.